# Eglot and Svelte

Tags: eglot

As the title suggests I have been struggling for a while now to get [eglot](https://github.com/joaotavora/eglot) to play nice with [svelte](https://github.com/sveltejs/language-tools), specifically I want to use `svelte` with `typescript`. `Svelte` provides a [language server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/svelte-language-server), but I can't get it to start. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the answer if someone happens upon the question.

```lisp
(use-package eglot
  :config
  (add-to-list 'eglot-server-programs
           '(svelte-mode . ("svelteserver" "--stdio"))))
```